# binding knockoutjs modelview with data from server mvc model

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, knockout-2.0

Let's take below as my MVC model class:

```
public class Candidate
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    public List<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }
}

public class Technology
{
    public string Technology { get; set; }
    public int ExperinceInMonths { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have a web api method which returns this modal data:

```
public class CandidateController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/Candidate
    public IEnumerable<Candidate> Get()
    {
        CandidateServiceClient client = new CandidateServiceClient();

        List<Candidate> candidateData = client.GetCandidateData();

        if (candidateData == null || candidateData.Count() == 0)
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent));

        return candidateData.AsEnumerable(); 
    }
     ...
```

Using Knockout let's say I have javascript something like this:

```
         $.get(url, function (result) {
           candidateViewModel.candidates(result);
           ko.applyBindings(candidateViewModel); 
       }); 
    });
```

> ```
>  var candidateViewModel = { candidates:  ko.observableArray([])};
> ```

With this background, my question is how to construct knockout viewmodel which has nested collection(s) ? (like Technology collection in this example.)

Looking for something like..

var myViewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable(''),
    lastName: ko.observable(''),
    ..
};

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should use ko.mapping.fromJS, just in case the model goes very complex, you do not need to change your view model.

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

The output on this is super messy, but it illustrates the idea. The thing here is to have `Candidate` and `Technology` models in your javascript, and use `arrayMap` to call their contructors. Here is [the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UaPUN/3/). Note: the models don't need to have observables properties if you don't plan on changing their values.

Models:

```
var Technology = function(name, monthsExperience){
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.monthsExperience = ko.observable(monthsExperience);
};

var Candidate = function(data){

    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName || '');
    this.lastName = ko.observable(data.LastName || '');
    this.email = ko.observable(data.Email || '');
    this.experience = ko.observable(data.Experience || '');

    this.technologies = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Technologies || [],
        function(i){
            return new Technology(i.Technology, i.ExperinceInMonths);
        }));
};
```

Main Viewmodel:

```
var App = function(initialData){
    this.candidates = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(initialData|| [],
        function(i){
            return new Candidate(i);
        }));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I just applied the correction. Your answer makes more sense to me. Please let me try this in.. Thanks!